# How can i deploy 1 python-django app and 1 java app on the same ec2 instance, where the java one serves the other app?

Tags: java, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment

I am new using AWS, I am trying to deploy a django rest api to and a java app into an aws ec2 instance, the fact is that the java app is used by the rest api, and i dont know if an ec2 instance can support both apps from diferent languages, i will really appreciate your help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

EC2 instances are just like any other machines with an operating system like windows or Linux or whatever you opted for at the time is EC2 AMI selection while creating that EC2 instance.

Now you can configure support for multiple languages (like Java and python and nodejs) on top of it and start using programs/applications written in those languages.

So to answer your question, yes a single EC2 can support not just 2 but any number of programming languages.

Comment: ok, thanks, you mean that if i deploy my python-django app in the ec2 instance and create a docker(instead of deploying the java app, cause i have the java app idocker image in docker hub, and it would be faster) in the same instance it will work?

Comment: I am not very well versed with Java so can't comment with authority on that, however I think that would work. But if it was outside docker then for sure it will work